# Compare a list to two others at the same time

Tags: python

I'm creating a simple tic-tac-toe game and I'm currently writing the function for checking the winner.
I'm trying to do the following:

```
['X', 'X', 'X'] == (['X', 'X', 'X'] or ['O', 'O', 'O'])
>>> True
```

In the case above, it returns `True` correctly. On the other hand, in this case returns `False`.

```
['O', 'O', 'O'] == (['X', 'X', 'X'] or ['O', 'O', 'O'])
>>> False
```

So how can I compare the list to two other simultaneously?

Comment: `["X", "X", "X"] in (["X", "X", "X"], ["O", "O", "O"])` or even `["X", "X", "X"] in (["X"]*3, ["O"]*3)`

Comment: Or, much easier and faster, if you're willing to rework your code a little: `"XXX" in {"XXX", "OOO"}`

Comment: @ddejohn Thank you! I'm ashamed I forgot the very basics. I tried the second one too and it worked handsomely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boolean expressions don't work like that - they don't work like an English sentence. You have to check if something is *in* something. Do something like:

`["X", "X", "X"] in (["X", "X", "X"], ["O", "O", "O"])`

and

`['O', 'O', 'O'] in (['X', 'X', 'X'], ['O', 'O', 'O'])`

When you use `or`, python sees each side of the operator as separate expressions. Have a look at this: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Answer (score 1):

Little addendum here on why the first result is `True` and the other `False`.

The `or` operator essentially works like this: Check if the first element is truthy. If it is, return it. If it is not, return the second element, even if it itself is falsy. To demonstrate:

```
>>> True or 1
True
>>> True or 0
True
>>> False or 1
1
>>> False or 0
0
```

In your case, the `or` operator encounters two non-empty lists, which always evaluate to `True`. Thus, `(['X', 'X', 'X'] or ['O', 'O', 'O'])` returns the first element,

```
>>> (['X', 'X', 'X'] or ['O', 'O', 'O'])
['X', 'X', 'X']
```

which is then compared to the left-hand side of the comparison operator.